# Where signal-cli stores the received messages and how to get them after receive command?

Tags: message

I cannot figure out how to read messages that was read by [signal-cli](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli) *receive* command.

I want to know where those messages are stored to read them locally ...

But looks like I can get messages only using [signal-cli](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli) *receive* command and after that them are not available ?!

Have somebody faced with the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, messages received via signal-cli must be stored by the caller, for example, by redirecting the output of signal-cli into an textfile:

```
signal-cli receive >> signal-messages.txt
```